# Add C# code to exe file directly without using the build command from visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exe

I have an exe file for my application using visual c#.

Whenever I have to change, I go to visual studio, change or add the code and build the application.

So that my exe file will be updated.

Now what I want to do is I just want to add new changes c# script to exe directly.

I don't want to build the application from visual studio again and again whenever I have to change the code in application.

Because sometimes it's take too long to build for big application.

Is there any tools or way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? Could you provide some code samples?

Comment: Do you want the delay once in a clump when you **compile** the code or smeared across every instruction when you **interperet** the script. All .Net code is compiled to Intermediate Language, then the IL is JIT compiled once for each session to match the machine its running on. If you don't want this, you'll have to use something other than .Net. There are a dirth of weakly typed scripting languages to choose from, pick the least tedious one that is hosted by the device you need to hack for.

Comment: (Unless you compile to Native Code) then you can skip the JIT bit at the cost of portability.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/174842

Comment: There is no C# interpreter that I'm aware of, certainly not one that ships with the .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1):

Uhm no.

The most you can do is avoid visual studio, edit the source files using a lightweight editor, and re-compile the assembly using msbuild (e.g., `msbuild.exe mysolution.sln`).

Answer (score 1):

If your project is large, building it can take some time. If you only need to change a small portion, you should seperate your project into smaller assemblies so your change in one assembly does not force a rebuild of your whole infrastructure.

Comment: If you change any `constant`, you must need to re-compile all the assemblies which depends on that `constant`. Else you'll be screwed :)

Answer (score 0):

If we're talking purely about building a project outside of visual studio then use an MSBuild scipt.

There is a decent tutorial here: http://goo.gl/MOseG

Note that you can reference static assemblies if you only want that project to be built, but be aware of stale references!

Now, let's have a look at the source of a your problem, large build that take a long time. I susggest you read here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx

It may be wise to split you solution into several sub solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried commandline compiling? It can be faster then Vs cause you dont have to open Vs (if you changed you code in notepad for example). Otherwise it nearly takes the same time (or longer cause you have to type in paths).

```
csc /out:YournewExe.exe YourFile.cs
```

Csc is the c# compiler and can be found at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\Version
Further information can be found here [Click](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could seperate that file which you change often into an own assembly and just rebuild that assembly. Of course you need to make an reference to that assembly in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just save your project file everytime instead of building it? And when you finish working on it for today,just build the app then.
You don't have to test the app everytime through the .exe file,do you?